# Make character look at mouse in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I have this code which should make the character look at the mouse. The character doesn't actually look at the mouse, and I don't know what's the causse.

```cs
float CameraDistance = Camera.main.transform.position.y - transform.position.y;
Vector3 WorldPoint = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
WorldPoint.z = CameraDistance;

float AngleRad = Mathf.Atan2(WorldPoint.y - transform.position.y, WorldPoint.x - transform.position.x);
float AngleDeg = (180 / Mathf.PI) * AngleRad;

Body.rotation = AngleDeg;
```

[image]

The red dot is where my mouse actually is.

Comment: Which of the objects axis should look to the mouse position? You just seem to be 90° off ..

Comment: On the Z axis only

Answer (score 2):

Instead of doing math operations, you should really look into 
            [transform.LookAt()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.LookAt.html). This method will solve this problem

Also instead of Camera.main, you should use **Input.mousePosition**

```
var mousePos = Input.mousePosition;
var wantedPos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(mousePos.x, mousePos.y, depth));

Body.LookAt(wantedPos);
```

Comment: Might be a problem though if the `Z` axis is not the one you want to be looking at the mouse .. happens pretty often in a 2D game that `Z` is pointing "forward into the screen" and you rather want e.g. the object's `Y` or `X` axis face towards the camera.

Comment: I'd like to only rotate the object on the Z axis, and if I use transform.LookAt it also rotates it on the X and Y axis

Comment: You need to change the vector you are looking at then. Try to change its x,y values to the values of Body.position.x and Body.position.y

Comment: ```Vector3 WorldPoint = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);

transform.LookAt(new Vector3(transform.position.x, transform.position.y, WorldPoint.z));
```

Now it doesn't rotate at all

Comment: The character is still only rotating on the X and Y axis

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to fix it. Here's the code:

```cs
Vector3 WorldPoint = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);

Vector3 Difference = WorldPoint - transform.position;
Difference.Normalize();

float RotationZ = Mathf.Atan2(Difference.y, Difference.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, 0f, RotationZ - 90);
```

I had to substract 90 from RotationZ so that the rotation would be accurate to the mouse position.